# Mudança de cor no gráfico com ChartJS não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery, chartjs

Poderiam me ajudar no caso abaixo?

Estou tentando mudar a cor do gráfico para vermelho, mas a alteração não está funcionando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
function Devolucao() {
if (CicloAtual != "") {
    var codCli = $("[id$=txtCodigo]").val();
    var ciclos = Array();
    var valores = Array();
    var sucesso = false; //Variavel auxiliar, para verificar se o gráfico será preenchido para exibir uma mensagem de alerta caso não haja dado

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "clientes.aspx/CarregarDevolucao",
        data: "{'codCli': '" + codCli + "','Ciclo': '" + CicloAtual + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            sucesso = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                ciclos[i] = data.d[i].string1.substring(4, 6) + "/" + data.d[i].string1.substring(0, 4);
                valores[i] = parseFloat(data.d[i].string2.replace(",", "."));
            }
            var buyerData = {
                labels: [ciclos[0], ciclos[1], ciclos[2], ciclos[3], ciclos[4], ciclos[5], ciclos[6], ciclos[7]],
                datasets: [{
                    fillColor: "rgba(178,34,34)",
                    strokeColor: "#8B0000",
                    pointColor: "#8B0000",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#9DB86D",
                    data: [valores[0], valores[1], valores[2], valores[3], valores[4], valores[5], valores[6], valores[7]],
                    label: "Devolução"
                }]
            }
            // get line chart canvas
            var buyers = document.getElementById('buyers2').getContext('2d');
            // draw line chart
            new Chart(buyers, {
                type: "line",
                data: buyerData,
            });
            //new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData);
            document.getElementById("grafico1").style.display = 'block';
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblAviso').attr('style', "display:none;");
            //montarvelocimetro(valores[7], CicloAtual);
        }
    })
    if (!sucesso) {
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblAviso').attr('style', "display:block;");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere os parâmetros de cor conforme indicado abaixo. E inclua uma função para conversão de cor Hexadecimal para RGBA. Inclui também a propriedade **backgroundColor** no dataset e foi.

[image: grafico exemplo]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  testeCor();
});

function testeCor() {
  var cor = "#e51c23";
  var valores = [10, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 15];
  var buyerData = {
    datasets: [{
      fillcolor: convertHexToRGBA(cor, 20),
      backgroundColor: convertHexToRGBA(cor, 20),
      strokeColor: cor,
      pointColor: cor,
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: cor,
      data: [valores[0], valores[1], valores[2], valores[3], valores[4], valores[5], valores[6], valores[7]],
      label: "Devolução"
    }]
  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: buyerData
  })
}

function convertHexToRGBA(n, t) {
  return n = n.replace("#", ""), r = parseInt(n.substring(0, 2), 16), g = parseInt(n.substring(2, 4), 16), b = parseInt(n.substring(4, 6), 16), result = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + t / 100 + ")"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</html>
```

Comment: Não houve alteração também...

Comment: Inclui um exemplo executável (role a barra de rolagem até o final). Inclui também a propriedade **backgroundColor** e funcionou.